# DolphinDB: the difference between percentile and quantile?

Tags: quantile, percentile, dolphindb

The functionality of `percentile` and `quantile` described in the DolphinDB user manual is similar. The main difference lies in the format of the input parameters, for example, `percentile(a, 25)` and `quantile(a, 0.25)`. Am I right in understanding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `percentile` function takes a percentage value (i.e., 25) as input, while `quantile` takes a floating number (i.e., 0.25)  as input.

Despite the only difference, the two functions return the same result. For example:

```
a=[6, 47, 49, 15, 42, 41, 7, 39, 43, 40, 36];
percentile(a, 50) //output: 40
quantile(a, 0.50)//output: 40
```